# Android dependency errors

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle

I have the following code in `build.gradle`

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.edit.mapgoogle"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
```

Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

Comment: What issue? That sure is a bunch of dependencies. Are you having trouble with them?

Comment: `fix this issue` which issue?

Comment: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1' **doesn't** exist.

Answer (score 0):

well these two lines don't have matched support library versions

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

try this instead

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

and look at this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification/52275051#52275051). I'm sure that's exactly the same problem of yours.

Comment: It is not exact. support-v4:28.0.0 exists.

Comment: yes you're right. I fixed it. thanks for mentioning.